как добавить данные в таблицу SQL по нажатию кнопки и вывод этой же таблицы в QtWidget
import sqlite3

from PyQt6.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

from заказ import Ui_Form as Ui_Form3
from завтрак import Ui_Form as Ui_Form4



class Zakaz(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Zakaz, self).__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        self.ui = Ui_Form3()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        #self.sto = self.parent.st  # 4 +++
        #print(f'self.sto ---> {self.parent.st}')
        #self.name_kasir = self.parent.kasir
        #print(f'self.name_kasir ---> {self.name_kasir}')

        #self.ui.label_6.setText(self.sto)
        #self.ui.label_7.setText(self.name_kasir)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.breakfast)

        #здесь по идеи хочу подключиться к базе данных и отображать ее
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('restoranDB.db')
        #db = sqlite3.connect('restoranDB.db')
        db.open()
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("zakaz")
        self.model.select()
        self.ui.tableWidget.setModel(self.model)
        #db.commit()
        #db.close()

    def breakfast(self):
        self.main_window = Zavtrak()
        self.main_window.show()
    

class Zavtrak(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_Form4()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.bt_1)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.bt_2)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.bt_3)
        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.bt_4)
        self.ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.bt_5)

    #Здесь хочу добавлять значение в базу данных
    def bt_1(self):
        Наименование = 'Крок-мадам'
        Раздел = Завтрак
        Цена = 300р
        #Номер заказа планирую брать в поле LineEdit которое пользователь введет сам 
        db = sqlite3.connect('restoranDB.db')
        self.cur = db.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO zakaz(Наименование, Раздел, Цена, Номер заказа) VALUES ")
    def bt_2(self):
        zav_2 = 'Омлет'
    def bt_3(self):
        zav_3 = 'Крем де-паризьен'
    def bt_4(self):
        zav_4 = 'Гужеры'
    def bt_5(self):
        zav_5 = 'Яйцо-кокот в горбушке'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Zakaz()
    window.show()
    app.exec()


код для Ui_Form3
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1106, 886)
        Form.setStyleSheet("\n"
"background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);\n"
"")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 110, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 110, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 110, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 230, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 230, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 230, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=Form)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(471, 100, 16, 771))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=Form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=Form)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 90, 1131, 16))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=Form)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 71, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(parent=Form)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 451, 721))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.tableWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=Form)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 10, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);")
        self.label_6.setText("")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=Form)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 60, 571, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);")
        self.label_7.setText("")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 350, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 350, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=Form)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 1111, 16))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.line_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(parent=Form)
        self.line_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1161, 16))
        self.line_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
        self.line_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Sunken)
        self.line_4.setObjectName("line_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent=Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(212, 110, 151, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.line.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        self.pushButton_3.raise_()
        self.pushButton_4.raise_()
        self.pushButton_5.raise_()
        self.pushButton_6.raise_()
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.line_2.raise_()
        self.label_5.raise_()
        self.tableWidget.raise_()
        self.label_7.raise_()
        self.label_6.raise_()
        self.pushButton_7.raise_()
        self.pushButton_8.raise_()
        self.line_3.raise_()
        self.line_4.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Стол №"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "завтрак"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "холодное"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "горячее"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "суп"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "выпечка"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "десерт"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Состав заказа:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "кассир:"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "винная \n"
"карта"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "кофе/чай"))

код для Ui_Form4
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(555, 366)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(213, 213, 213);")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=Form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, -10, 171, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 50, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 50, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 170, 171, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Palatino Linotype")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(193, 193, 193);")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Завтрак"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Крок-мадам"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Завтрак"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "омлет"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Крем \n"
"де-паризьен"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Гужеры"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Яйцо-кокот\n"
" в горбушке"))

